# How do I successfully create a hook for an email override?

Tags: hooks, email

I'm creating an online apartment rental application using Visual Form Builder Pro.  I need to have completed forms go to certain managers based on the property selection.  Once a user selects a property location and submits the form, it must be routed via email to the appropriate apartment manager.  For example, I choose Arlington Arms Apartments in my application, complete the form and submit it. The Arlington Arms manager should be the only individual who receives my completed application via email.  I started out with creating a vfb_override_email_114.php file but I'm not sure where to save it so that my code will be picked up once a submission occurs.  I'm inexperienced with code so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Application: http://simco-apts.com/testsite/?page_id=140

Code so far:

```
<?php
/*
Email Override for Applications 
*/
?>
<?php 
add_action( 'vfb_override_email_114', 'vfb_action_override_email', 10, 5 );

function vfb_action_override_email( $emails_to, $form_subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ){
    // Checks radio button. Use Merge Tag to get $_POST id
    if ( 'Arlington Arms' == $_POST['vfb-5'] )
        $emails_to = array( 'arlingtonarms@simco-apts.com' );
    elseif ( 'Crestview' == $_POST['vfb-5'] )
        $emails_to = array( 'crestview@simco-apts.com' );

    // Send the mail
    foreach ( $emails_to as $email ) {
        wp_mail( $email, $form_subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress uses the PHPMailer class for sending mail. Before calling wp_mail, you can manipulate the `$phpmailer` object using the `phpmailer_init` filter.

```
//Place this inside of your form callback before wp_mail()
add_filter('phpmailer_init', 'foobar_phpmailer', 99999, 1);

function foobar_phpmailer(&$phpmailer){
    //Manipulate the phpmailer object here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I added your code after my last email listing.  Is this correct:

 `elseif ( 'Woodgate North' == $_POST['vfb-5'] )
        $emails_to = array( 'woodgatenorth@simco-apts.com' );
 
add_filter('phpmailer_init', 'foobar_phpmailer', 99999, 1);

function foobar_phpmailer(&$phpmailer){
    //Manipulate the phpmailer object here
}
 
    // Send the mail
    foreach ( $emails_to as $email ) {
        wp_mail( $email, $form_subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
    }
}`

Comment: @Julie Are you altering anything other than recipients?

Comment: @ Brian, I'm very new at coding so please forgive me if I'm slow at this.  I created this new .php document with coding specific only to recipients.  I have 21 apartments which means 21 different email addresses.  I started the first apartment email address with `if` and the remaining 20 email addresses with `elseif`. I'm not sure if I named my document correctly and I have it saved in the root folder of my theme. Is that the correct location? I assume I just upload the new document via FTP and somehow it will work?

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was wondering if you saw my response on 7/23?